# String interpolation doesn't work in php

Tags: php, interpolation

i'm confused.
I've two php pages with similar code, one work one not.
The problem is the script prints the variable name instead of its content
The one is not working is

```html
<?php
$cod=htmlspecialchars($_POST["codice"]);
$nom=htmlspecialchars($_POST["nome"]);
$cog=htmlspecialchars($_POST["cognome"]);
$nato=htmlspecialchars($_POST["nato"]);
$ind=htmlspecialchars($_POST["indirizzo"]);
$cap=htmlspecialchars($_POST["cap"]);
$cit=htmlspecialchars($_POST["citta"]);
$pro=htmlspecialchars($_POST["provincia"]);
$cf=htmlspecialchars($_POST["cf"]);
$tel=htmlspecialchars($_POST["tel"]);
$mail=htmlspecialchars($_POST["mail"]);
$classe=htmlspecialchars($_POST["classe"]);
$scelta=htmlspecialchars($_POST["radio"]);
$pagamento=htmlspecialchars($_POST["pagamento"]);
$ipad=htmlspecialchars($_POST["ipad"]);
$colore=htmlspecialchars($_POST["colore"]);

//INVIO MAIL 
$to = "xxxi@xxx.xx";
$subject = "SOGGETTO";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>TITOLO</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>TITOLO</p>
CODICE ISCRIZIONE: $cod 
<br /> NOME: $nom 
<br /> COGNOME: $cog 
<br /> NATO IL : $nato 
<br /> INDIRIZZO: $ind 
<br /> CAP : $cap 
<br /> CITTA: $cit 
<br /> PROVINCIA: $pro 
<br /> TELEFONO: $tel 
<br /> CF: $cf 
<br /> SCELTA: $scelta 
<br /> MAIL: $mail 
<br /> ULTIMA CLASSE CON SUCCESSO: $classe 
<br /> MODALITA DI PAGAMENTO: $pagamento 
<br /> IPAD: $ipad 
<br /> COLORE IPAD: $colore 
<br /> ACCETTO IL CONTRATTO = SI
<br /> FINE DEL MESSAGGIO
</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
// More headers
$headers = "From: xx@xx.xx\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: xx@xx.xx\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: xx@xx.xxt\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

?>
```

But I've another script that works and it seems to be equal.
Don't know why.

```html
<?php
$nome=htmlspecialchars($_POST["nome"]);
$cognome=htmlspecialchars($_POST["cognome"]);
$sesso=htmlspecialchars($_POST["sesso"]);
$giorno=htmlspecialchars($_POST["giorno"]);
$mese=htmlspecialchars($_POST["mese"]);
$anno=htmlspecialchars($_POST["anno"]);
$citta=htmlspecialchars($_POST["citta"]);
$email=htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
$tel=htmlspecialchars($_POST["tel"]);
$corsofrequentato=htmlspecialchars($_POST["corsofrequentato"]);
$ultimaclasse=htmlspecialchars($_POST["ultimaclasse"]);
$corsodafrequentare=htmlspecialchars($_POST["corsodafrequentare"]);
$primo=htmlspecialchars($_POST["primo"]);
$secondo=htmlspecialchars($_POST["secondo"]);
$terzo=htmlspecialchars($_POST["terzo"]);
$quarto=htmlspecialchars($_POST["quarto"]);
$quinto=htmlspecialchars($_POST["quinto"]);
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ita');
$oggi=strftime("%Y%m%d");
$adesso=date("9His");
$keyword="2";
//Invio MAIL 
$to = "xxx@xxx.xxx";
$subject = "soggetto";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>TITOLO</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>SOGGETTO </p>
<br /> NOME: $nome
<br /> COGNOME: $cognome
<br /> SESSO: $sesso
<br /> DATA DI NASCITA: $giorno/$mese/$anno
<br /> CITTA': $citta
<br /> EMAIL: $email
<br /> TEL: $tel
<br /> ULTIMO CORSO: $corsofrequentato
<br /> ULTIMA CLASSE: $ultimaclasse
<br /> CORSO RICHIESTO: $corsodafrequentare
<br /> PRIMA: $primo
<br /> SECONDA: $secondo
<br /> TERZA: $terzo
<br /> QUARTA: $quarto
<br /> QUINTA: $quinto
<br /> DATA RICHIESTA: $oggi
<br /> ORA RICHIESTA: $adesso
<br /> PAROLA CHIAVE: $keyword

</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
// More headers
$headers = "From: xxx@xxx.xx\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: xxx@xxx.xx\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: xxx@xxx.xx\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

?>
```

The first outputs 
NOME: $nom 
    
 COGNOME: $cog 
    
 NATO IL : $nato 
    
 INDIRIZZO: $ind 
    
 CAP : $cap 
    
 CITTA: $cit 
The second outputs correctly with the content of the variable

Could someone help me?
Thank you.
P.S.: I'm using Wordpress with phpeverywhere to insert php into wp pages

Comment: _“P.S.: I'm using Wordpress with phpeverywhere to insert php into wp pages”_ - so essentially what you are saying is, you chose the most terrible way possible to create a contact form(?), instead of using a tool that is build for the job, such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/ ...?

Comment: I've tried contact form 7 but it can't send data to a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:
The problem was the form on the prev page. It didn't send the right value but the name of variable, so i was convinced that the error was in the result page.
So the code is correct, if someone need it.
Thanks all.